# WINSOCK2 WSAAsyncSelect deprecated issue

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, asynchronous

Hi I am using winsock2 and I am trying to get async communication. 
I tried with [TCP server msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737593(v=vs.85).aspx) which is waiting for accept.

I tried with [WSAAsyncSelect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540(v=vs.85).aspx) before the listen function.

```
WSAAsyncSelect(ListenSocket,
        m_hWnd,
        WM_SOCKET,
        (FD_CLOSE | FD_ACCEPT | FD_READ));
```

and is showing the following error ..

```
Error   C4996   'WSAAsyncSelect': Use WSAEventSelect() instead or define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS to disable deprecated API warnings
```

How can I solve this .. Thanks in advance ..

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error message suggested? I.e. looking into the [`WSAEventSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) function?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes now I am working on it .. just want to know in any way I can use `WSAAsyncSelect`. bcz i have a sample pgm fr that ..

Comment: Then the error message tells you how to do that too.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried the define after the winsock2 header. . Now it is working (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get rid of that warning you can define `#define _WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS`
 at the top of your source file, which will disable there types of warnings.

That said, it might be worth listening to this warning and using [`WSAEventSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741576(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.
Since `WSAEventSelect` signals an event instead of posting a message to the Window's message queue which is what [`WSAAsyncSelect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does. Posting into the message queue is slower and adds additional processing that isn't really needed.

I have an example laying around which i'll post here for you:
... I may have gone overboard... but it's all useful and relevant.

### Setup Listening Socket

```
if ( socket_name == INVALID_SOCKET )
{
    P_ERR( "Could not create socket ( Id: %d ): %d\n", id, WSAGetLastError() );
    return INVALID_SOCKET;
}

rerror = bind( socket_name, (SOCKADDR*)&sock_addr, sizeof( sock_addr ) );
if ( rerror != SOCKET_ERROR )
{
    rerror = listen( socket_name, MAX_LISTEN_QUEUE );

    if ( rerror != SOCKET_ERROR )
    {
        /* Selects the events that will trigger the `socket_event` windows event. */
        /* socket_event was created using 'CreateEvent( NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL );' */
        WSAEventSelect( socket_name, socket_event, FD_ALL_EVENTS );

        if ( !startStatusThread() )
        {
            rerror = 1;
            P_ERR( "Status thread failed: %d\n", id );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        P_ERR( "listen() error %d : Error %d\n", id, WSAGetLastError() );
        closesocket( socket_name );
    }
}
else
{
    P_ERR( "bind() error ( Id: %d ): %d\n", id, WSAGetLastError() );
    closesocket( socket_name );
}
```

### Process Events From Socket

```
    /* waits 10ms for events in the event array ( in this case just 1 event as socket_event ). */
    rerror = WSAWaitForMultipleEvents( 1, &socket_event, FALSE, 10, FALSE );
    if ( rerror == WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT )
    {
        continue; /* this block of code runs in a while loop. */
    }

    index = rerror - WSA_WAIT_EVENT_0; /* get the smallest index of a triggered event */
    if ( rerror != WSA_WAIT_TIMEOUT && rerror != WSA_WAIT_FAILED )
    {
        /* returns a list of the events that occured. */
        rerror = WSAEnumNetworkEvents( socket_name, socket_event, &events );
        if ( rerror == SOCKET_ERROR )
        {
            P_ERR( "WSAEnumNetworkEvents Error %d: Id: %d\n", WSAGetLastError(), pThis->id );
            continue;
        }
        /* look below for this function. */
        handleNetworkEvents( events, index );
    }
```

### Handling the Events.

```
void
handleNetworkEvents( WSANETWORKEVENTS e, const int socket_index )
{
    int rerror = 0;
    /* on accept. */
    if ( e.lNetworkEvents & FD_ACCEPT )
    {
        if ( e.iErrorCode[FD_ACCEPT_BIT] == 0 )
        {
            onAccept();
        }
        else
        {
            P_ERR( "Unknown network event error %d\n", id );
        }
    }
    /* on connect */
    if ( e.lNetworkEvents & FD_CONNECT )
    {
        if ( e.iErrorCode[FD_CONNECT_BIT] == 0 )
        {
            sendRead(); /* send first read request */
        }
        else
        {
            P_ERR( "Unknown network event error %d\n", id );
        }
    }
    /* on successful read */
    if ( e.lNetworkEvents & FD_READ )
    {
        sendRead(); /* get read data and queue another request. */
        callback( id, inBuffer.buf, lastReadSize ); /* process data. */
    }
    /* on close. */
    if ( e.lNetworkEvents & FD_CLOSE )
    {
        /* close the current event and make a new one ready for a new connection. */
        onClose( socket_index );
    }
}
```

Comment: @VivekAnanthan Thanks, I hope its quite useful, I had to cut out quite a bit of code to make it simple enough so take it as an example of use and not a completely working example and you should do well.

Comment: I fail to see the interest of WSAEventSelect() in a windowed application; replacing Async with Event means that if you want your windowed application to stay responsive, you have to manage the list of events yourself, and change the message loop to use MsgWaitForMultipleEvents() instead of whatever you were doing (which also means, no DialogBox(), so if you were using EndDialog() you now need to change that too...)
WSAEventSelect may be good for console apps (and even then, waiting on consoles has its own problems) but Async is definitely the best choice for a windowed app!

Comment: Hi @Medinoc if you feel like Microsoft has made a mistake and you have a better answer, please feel free to post the answer in this question so you can properly explain the reasoning and give examples.